# How can I change absolute URL to relative in WordPress -> pagination -> previous\next_posts_link?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, pagination, relative-path

I have:
`<?php previous_posts_link(' '); ?>` -> `<a href="http://example.com/path"> </a>`
I need:
`<?php previous_posts_link(' '); ?>` -> `<a href="/path"> </a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress by default uses absolute URLs.

You can create a filter that hooks to `get_pagenum_link` and change the link:

```
add_filter('get_pagenum_link', function($url) {
    $base = 'http://example.com/';
    if (0 === strpos($url, $base)) {
        $url = '/'.substr($url, strlen($base));
    }
    return $url;
});
```

Alternatively you can, by using an output buffer, catch the whole pages output and change links according to your needs inside the buffer. `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` are helpful here. Another helpful library is [`Net_URL2`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2), useful functions are [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`http_build_url`](http://php.net/http_build_url).